# How can I get match in Type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have component in which I have to use match.params, but when I try it I have an error. How can I get match params in my case?

Component

```
type MainInfoProps = {
  mainInfo: IUser,
  boxShadow?: number,
};

export const UserCard: React.FC<MainInfoProps> = (props) => {
  return()
}
```

Error

```
Property 'match' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<MainInfoProps>'
```

Comment: There is no code in your question trying to use the property `match`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Fundamentally, the props type you've shown doesn't have a `match` property, so it's not surprising that you get a complaint if you're trying to use `match` on `props`, but it's impossible to really help without more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RouteComponentProps` which is a generic type that accepts the *params* object type.

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

type MainInfoProps = {
   mainInfo: IUser;
   boxShadow?: number;
} & RouteComponentProps<{ paramOne: string; paramTwo: string }>;
```

Then you will be able to use it:

```
props.match.params.paramOne;
```

Comment: in this case everywhere I use this component I have to transfer paramOne and paramTwo. Maybe there is exist another way?

Comment: @Volodumr Then make it optional so in case you dont want to pass any params, typescript wont complain.

Comment: even if I do this RouteComponentProps<{ paramOne?: string; paramTwo?: string }> I have error that I have to transfer something

Comment: @Volodumr Showing me the error would be a good start

Comment: Type '{ mainInfo: any; boxShadow: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{ paramOne?: string | undefined; 
}, StaticContext, unknown>': history, location, match  TS2739

Comment: @Volodumr Did you connect the component with the router? With e.g. `withRouter` HoC?

Comment: Like this export default withRouter(UserCard);

Comment: @Volodumr Should be okey now.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: make the whole RouteComponentProps optional.  type MainInfoProps = YourProps & Partial<RouteComponentProps<YourParams>>.  But note that if you aren’t always passing a match with params, you’re going to have trouble using the params inside the component.